# Software Updater has closed unexpectedly

Tags: updates, update-manager

I'm frequently getting this update error icon on the upper bar.

[image]

Well, this error by itself is annoying, but I always solve it by running the Software Updater and installing the pending updates. But this time it simply didn't work. The updater shows the following error message instead:

[image]

Relaunching it as the message suggests won't work. I've also tried to update by the terminal, but it displays the following error:

[image]

The error icon is still there and the updater keeps showing the same error message. I've also tried the following commands (which other people suggested on other questions to fix this problem):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and

```
sudo sed -i.bak '1d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Neither of these work either.

How could I fix this? Thanks.

---

Edit: I tried to mark the option "Ignore future problems of this program version" and now the Software Update won't even run! What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge mono-runtime
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```